# Swiftui macos image as a button rendering as an image on top of a small button

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

From looking at code online, it seems the following code in swiftUI

```
Button(action: {
    print("Button tapped!")
}) {
    Image("iFEN")
}
```

should render the image iFEN as a button that can be clicked. However - instead it renders this:

[image]

, the image on top of a small button that can be clicked. Why is this the case? Is something different between macos and ios in this case?

Comment: Change the bordered property.  And change the button rect.

Comment: @ElTomato How do I change the button-rect? And does the bordered property just add a border to the image?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use a different button style:

```
Button(action: {
    print("Button tapped!")
}) {
    Image("iFEN")
}
.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
```

---

Button styles can vary drastically by platform. [Here is a table](https://dev.to/maeganwilson_/button-styles-in-swiftui-1000) that shows which styles are available on each.